# When express a first-order system as a block diagram with feedback?

Tags: control

I've seen in many places that a first-order system is depicted as a block diagram using an integrator. For example, this figure comes from https://www.tutorialspoint.com/control_systems/control_systems_response_first_order.htm

[image]

What is the rationale for using this depiction rather than just using the transfer function bock itself as in (https://electricalacademia.com/control-systems/block-diagrams-in-control-systems/):

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Logically, there is no difference, of course. However, when it comes down to implementation, engineers tend to stick to basic building blocks, both in terms of SW libraries and HW components. Among all the basic building blocks, the integrator is the most important in the context of dynamical systems.

Comment: Thanks, I thought there might have been a deeper reason. What you say makes sense.